# Binary numbers instead of one hot vectors

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, computer-vision, neural-network

While doing logistic regression, it is common practice to use one hot vectors as desired result. So, `no of classes = no of nodes in output layer`. We don't use index of word in vocabulary(or a class number in general) because that may falsely indicate closeness of two classes. But why can't we use binary numbers instead of one-hot vectors?

i.e if there are 4 classes, we can represent each class as 00,01,10,11 resulting in `log(no of classes)` nodes in output layer.

Comment: that's a valid optimization, you could also use a huffman coding to find these bits. keep in mind that you probably need to change your optimization objective, eg softmax wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: this is nearly as (in)valid as using integers - you again introduce many of relations in between classes (since things that are "a bit 10 and a bit 01" will result with high probability in either "00" or "11")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is fine if you encode with binary. But you probably need to add another layer (or a filter) depending on your task and model. Because your encoding now implicates invalid shared features due to the binary representation.

For example, a binary encoding for input (`x = [x1, x2]`):

```
'apple' = [0, 0]
'orange' = [0, 1]
'table' = [1, 0]
'chair' = [1, 1]
```

It means that `orange` and `chair` share same feature `x2`. Now with predictions for two classes `y`:

```
'fruit' = 0
'furniture' = 1
```

And linear optimization model (`W = [w1, w2]` and bias `b`) for labeled data sample:

```
(argmin W) Loss = y - (w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + b)
```

Whenever you update `w2` weights for `chair` as `furniture` you get an undesirable update as if predicting `orange` as `furniture` as well.

In this particular case, if you add another layer `U = [u1, u2]`, you can probably solve this issue:

```
(argmin U,W) Loss = y - (u1 * (w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + b) +
                         u2 * (w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + b) +
                         b2)
```

Ok, why not avoid this miss representation, by using one-hot encoding. :)

Comment: What if one would use binary encoding instead of one-hot encoding for the outputs of the network?

Comment: onehot encoding is like binary encoding, (`0` for absent and `1` for presence of things), but as implementations it depends on how you want to calculate the loss. For example if you want to have crossentropy distance between your data and the predictions you definitely need vectors. So it is standard to have float vectors representing one-hots.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I understand all of this. My question is this: you have a setup with one-hot encoding as vectors for outputs. Would changing the output format to binary encoded numbers instead result in the same problems you outlined above? (The results encode categories...)

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed the last question that time. So, now that I revisited the question and your question. I should say: It is more problematic to represent target categories with binary numbers. The categorical nature of the target results indicates that there is no order, hierarchy, or shared dimensions between categories. Encoding them with binary is problematic because of these aspects of representation. Then the question is how would you quantify binaries in logistic regression?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding

Binary encoding (and in fact, base-anything encoding) is supported in category_encoders. In our case, we end up with feature per place in the binary string, so it's not one feature with value '011' or '010' its 3 with [0, 1, 1] and [0, 1, 0] respectively.